# connect ETIMEDOUT 4.240.83.83:27017 , MongoDB Compass error

Tags: mongodb

when i am connecting MongoDB compass with atlas I am getting this error

how to fix the issue , i made cluster many times, but I got same issue all the time, every time iP address shown on images change but remain same , don't know how to fix it, please help

Answer (score 0):

Your mongodb database network will only be allowed to certain ip address only.

If you have changed your network then you might not be able to access it.

Make sure that your current IP address is listed in the network access tab.

You can find this tab in the left panel, where the database,datalake,database access options are listed,

Go in the network access options,

Then if your current IP address is not listed, then add it,

And if you want to access your database from any network,
Then add 0.0.0.0 address in the list

Comment: It works fine with the mongosh , but still I will try 0.0.0.0, current ip is listed but still issue remain same